# Make a class that cannot be instantiated?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, inheritance

Suppose that I have a class `Bar`. I want to use `Bar` uniquely as a base class, e.g.:

```
class Foo : public Bar
```

I want to disallow `Bar` from being able to be instantiated. In other words, I want `Bar object;` to be an error. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Protected constructor?  Make it an abstract class?

Comment: make bar abstract?

Comment: Making it abstract means defining a pure virtual function (e.g. `virtual void fizz() = 0;`) right? I don't want to do that, because there is no use case for me to have such a function.

Comment: Yes you do have a use case for such a function.  Your use case is "to prevent your class from being instantiated".  In any case, if you make the pure virtual function private, nobody will ever know you have it.  It will be between just you and the compiler.

Comment: Would using a protected constructor be cleaner? E.g. `class Foo {
protected:
  Foo();
}`

Comment: Consider:  Not quite what you asked for, but note that if a) all ctor's of Bar are protected, and b) all other attributes (method or data) of Bar are protected or private, Bar would be 'useless' to anything other than a derived instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. You're essentially asking, how to make a class *abstract*.

In some other languages there is a specifier keyword that can be used to declare a class abstract, but not in c++. In c++ a class is abstract if it has at least one pure virtual member function.

Almost always, an abstract class naturally has a pure virtual function for the derived classes to implement, but in case your base class does not have one, there is a trick: Declare the destructor of the abstract class as pure virtual.

PS. Note that unlike other pure virtual functions, a destructor must always have a definition.

Comment: `protected` constructor?

Comment: Is a protected constructor a cleaner/equivalent way of achieving the non-instantiability?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that doesn't prevent a child class from constructing an instance of the parent as a non-base-subobject. Now, I don't know why that would be important, but that's what I understand was asked for.

Comment: @user2079303 That's a great point. I will go with your method of making the destructor pure virtual. I was not aware that a pure virtual destructor can still have a definition.

Comment: @space_voyager  & πάνταῥεῖ also, with the visibility approach, you must remember to mark all constructors, including the copy ones.

Comment: @space_voyager also to clarify: All pure virtual functions can have a definition. This is sometimes useful for a "canonical" definition of the interface. Destructor is just different in that it *must* have a definition.

Comment: Thanks for detailing!

Comment: @space_voyager There is one slight difference with both approaches (besides what was said before). If you use virtual destructor that will generate vtables and size of an object will change.

Comment: @Logman thanks for pointing out. Is this a background detail for my own knowledge, or something to be actively concerned about?

Comment: @space_voyager sometimes you can map memory to an object (I do not consider whether it is good or bad practice) and vtables will most likely prevent such functionality.